# $∇ \cdot( ∇\times u)=0$ What is the concept of this.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics, divergence-operator, curl

Why is it $=0$ . I understand the equation. But I don’t understand the concept of it. Is it because the divergence of it or the curl?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: div(curl) of any 3 dimensional vector field is always $0$ . That is for any vector valued function $F=F_{1}\hat{i}+F_{2}\hat{j}+F_{3}\hat{k}$ , you have $div(curl(F))=0$ which means that $\nabla\cdot \bigg(\nabla\times F\bigg)= 0 $

Comment: "Is it because the divergence of it or the curl?" The reason it happens isn't simply 'because' of one operation or the other, what is important is how doing the two operations in sequence behaves.

Comment: Conceptually you can also understand it as rotational field has no sinks or sources, which means 'vectors of the field only twist around' but don't 'converge' towards a single point nor emanate from a particular point.

Answer (score 1):

If you have three vectors $a$, $b$, $c$ then $a\cdot b\times c$ is equal to the volume of the shape formed by the three vectors, so if $a$ and $b$ say are parallel then $a\cdot b\times c=0$. Like multiplication, differentiation is commutative, so $\nabla\cdot\nabla\times u$ is identically zero.
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot\nabla\times u
&=D_1(D_3 u_2-D_2 u_3)+D_2(D_3 u_1-D_1 u_3)+D_3(D_1 u_2-D_2 u_1)\\
&=(D_2 D_3-D_3 D_2)u_1+....\\
&=0+0+0
\end{align}
$$

There isn't any "obvious" geometric interpretation of this since $\nabla\cdot$ and $\nabla\times$ are not actually vectors but operators.

But the divergence measures how much of the vector field is going in and out of a volume (Gauss's divergence theorem), whereas the curl measures how much the vector field is rotating on a surface (Stoke's theorem), so you can view the divergence as perpendicular to a surface (in and out), and the curl as parallel to the surface (rotating around the surface). I think that is the intuitive picture most people have.

Answer (score 0):

It is a general result that can be proven easily.

If $F(x,y,z)=F_{1}(x,y,z)\hat{i}+F_{2}(x,y,z)\hat{j}+F_{3}(x,y,z)\hat{k}$ is a smooth vector field then $\text{div}(\text{curl}(F))=0$ . That is $\nabla\cdot\bigg(\nabla\times F\bigg)=0$ .

The proof is very easy just by computation.

$$\nabla\times F= \bigg(\frac{\partial{F_{3}}}{\partial y}- \frac{\partial{F_{2}}}{\partial z}\bigg)\hat{i}-\bigg(\frac{\partial{F_{3}}}{{\partial x}}- \frac{\partial{F_{1}}}{\partial z}\bigg)\hat{j}+\bigg(\frac{\partial{F_{2}}}{\partial x}- \frac{\partial{F_{1}}}{\partial y}\bigg)\hat{k}$$ .

Now $$\nabla\cdot (\nabla\times F) = \frac{\partial^{2} F_{3}}{\partial y \partial x} - \frac{\partial^{2} F_{2}}{\partial z \partial x} - \frac{\partial^{2} F_{3}}{\partial y \partial x}+\frac{\partial^{2} F_{1}}{\partial z \partial y} + \frac{\partial^{2} F_{2}}{\partial z \partial x} - \frac{\partial^{2} F_{1}}{\partial y \partial z} = 0  $$